# import a Android Studio Project

Tags: java, android, github, import, project

I'm new to the android programming area and would like to import a chat project from GitHub. This project uses FIREBASE. But, I can't run, it makes a lot of mistakes.

"Compilation is not supported for following modules: app. Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project"

"the package name is already used in firebase" // I tried to change the package name.. but doesn't work.

this is the project https://github.com/hieuapp/android-firebase-chat
Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `google-services.json` file from firebase, is having problems compiling.

I had the same problem because github wasn't pulling correctly, and all you have to do is just add that file manually to your android project.

Hope it helps.